# How to Convert SVG to PNG in Node.js, Including Base64-Encoded Images?

Tags: node.js, image, svg, png, jpeg

Hello Stack Overflow Community,

I am working on a Node.js project where I need to convert SVG files to PNG & JPEG format. My SVG files are unique in that they include images encoded as base64 data. I've tried using the sharp library for this, but I'm encountering issues where the base64 images are either not rendered correctly or are missing in the final PNG output. Additionally, I need the conversion to maintain a high quality in the final PNG image.

Here are my specific requirements:

- The solution should be implementable in a Node.js environment.
- It needs to handle SVGs with embedded base64-encoded images properly.
- The quality of the PNG & JPEG output should be high, preserving the fidelity of the original SVG.

I am open to using other Node.js libraries or external tools that can be invoked from a Node.js application. Any examples or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance for your help!

I tried to use this following method:

```
const sharp = require('sharp');
const fs = require('fs');

async function convertSvgToPng(svgFilePath) {
    const outputFilePath = svgFilePath.replace('.svg', '.png');
    const svgBuffer = fs.readFileSync(svgFilePath);

    await sharp(svgBuffer)
        .png()
        .toFile(outputFilePath);

    return outputFilePath;
}
```

This code does not seem to handle base64-encoded images within the SVGs well and also quality is not upto the mark.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample code that create jpeg file from SVG and base64.

```
 async function getQRForGroup(groupuuid, batch) {
  //TODO: fix this for the new host, and the new gallery URL 
  var sURLForGroup = config.BASE_HREF + '/gallery/view/' + groupuuid;
  //var b64String =  async sURLForGroup => await QRCode.toDataURL(sURLForGroup);
  var b64String = null;
  var fontSize = 18;
  var textColor = "#000000";
  var text = "Tachiba";
  var qrCodeUrl = await QRCode.toDataURL(sURLForGroup, { width: 500, margin: 5 });


  // Use sharp to open the generated QR code image
  var b64Str = await sharp(Buffer.from(qrCodeUrl.split(',')[1], 'base64'))
    .jpeg() // You can specify the output format here (e.g., png, webp, etc.)
    .toBuffer()
    .then((inputBuffer) => {
      // Use the buffer to add text to the image using the composite method
      return sharp(inputBuffer)
        .jpeg()
        .composite([
          {
            //viewbox="10 5 100 100"
            input: Buffer.from(`<svg ><text x="0" y="33" font-size="45" fill="${textColor}">${text}</text></svg>`),
            gravity: 'south', // Position of the text on the image
          },
          {
            input: Buffer.from(`
                <svg width="120" height="80">
                <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#ffffff"/>
                <text text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="central" x="60" y="55" font-size="38" fill="${textColor}">${batch}</text>
                </svg>`),
            gravity: 'center', // Position of the text on the image
          }
        ])
        .toBuffer();
    })
    .then((outputBuffer) => {
      // Convert the final image buffer to a Base64-encoded string
      b64String = outputBuffer.toString('base64');
      return b64String;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      errorLogger('Error adding text to the QR code image:', err);
    });
  return "data:image/png;base64," + b64Str;
}
```

Please check.